# SPARQL's FILTER() not working as expected

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I'm trying to load a list of African countries from Wikidata together with their currency. This is my current query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item $itemLabel ?currency ?currencyLabel ?currencyEndDate
  WHERE {
    ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q3624078.                                # select only sovereign states
    ?item wdt:P706/wdt:P361*|wdt:P361*|wdt:P30 wd:Q15.        # select items which are geographically in Africa

    ?item p:P31 ?statement.
    ?statement ps:P31 wd:Q3624078.
    FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?statement pq:P582 ?end. }            # filter out items which are not sovereign states anymore
    FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q3024240. }          # filter out historical countries

    OPTIONAL {
      ?item p:P38 ?currencyStatement.
      ?currencyStatement ps:P38 ?currency.
      OPTIONAL {
        ?currencyStatement pq:P582 ?currencyEndDate.
      }
      #FILTER (?currencyEndDate = "")
    }

    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
  }
  ORDER BY ASC($itemLabel)
```

You can try it [here](https://query.wikidata.org/#%20%20%20%20SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fitem%20%24itemLabel%20%3Fcurrency%20%3FcurrencyLabel%20%3FcurrencyEndDate%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ3624078.%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20select%20only%20sovereign%20states%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP706%2Fwdt%3AP361%2a%7Cwdt%3AP361%2a%7Cwdt%3AP30%20wd%3AQ15.%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20select%20items%20which%20are%20geographically%20in%20Africa%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20p%3AP31%20%3Fstatement.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fstatement%20ps%3AP31%20wd%3AQ3624078.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%20%3Fstatement%20pq%3AP582%20%3Fend.%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20filter%20out%20items%20which%20are%20not%20sovereign%20states%20anymore%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ3024240.%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20filter%20out%20historical%20countries%0A%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20p%3AP38%20%3FcurrencyStatement.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FcurrencyStatement%20ps%3AP38%20%3Fcurrency.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FcurrencyStatement%20pq%3AP582%20%3FcurrencyEndDate.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23FILTER%20%28%3FcurrencyEndDate%20%3D%20%22%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20ORDER%20BY%20ASC%28%24itemLabel%29%0A).

As you can see, some countries have more than one currency, but mostly this is due to a past currency which was eventually replaced. The past currencies have a end date qualifier (P:582), which is loaded into the variable `?currencyEndDate`.

Now I'd like to use `?currencyEndDate` in the `FILTER` clause at line 17. But as soon as I activate this line, the currencies are gone from all results.

If I move the `FILTER` line two lines further down (outside of the `OPTIONAL`), then I get no results at all.

I'd be grateful for an explanation of

- how to do it
- and why my queries don't work as expected.

Comment: Are you looking for `FILTER (!bound(?currencyEndDate))`?

Comment: The more intuitive way would be to do `FILTER NOT EXISTS {?currencyStatement pq:P582 ?currencyEndDate. }` instead of the OPTIONAL + FILTER to avoid old currencies. And as cygri said, it has to be `FILTER(!bound(?currencyEndDate))` - your `FILTER` just checks if there is a value which is the empty string. Note, the combination `OPTIONAL {...} FILTER(!bound())` was used in SPARQL 1.0 to query for non existence but with SPARQL 1.1 the `NOT EXISTS` feature was introduced which is more understandable for many people.

Comment: Thanks @cygri and AKSW.